# Writing xml string with StAX

Tags: java, jaxb, stax

Is it possible to write an xml chunk directly using StAX?
I know I can use an `XMLStreamWriter` with `writeStartElement`, `writeCharacters` and `writeEndElement` but there is no flexibility for xml strings.

How do I get around this limitation considering I have to write a large xml file (> 100 MB).

I have arbitrary xml strings like this, sometimes with a fairly complex structure, that need to be added together with some other details to form the final xml file. This is just an example not the actual xml string.

```
<food>
<name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
<price>$7.95</price>
<description>
Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream
</description>
<calories>900</calories>
</food>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is a method [`writeCharacters()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.html#writeCharacters-java.lang.String-) on [`XMLStreamWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.html) this doesn't do what you want. It's after all escaping `'<', '>', '&'`

since you already have the XML String in memory you might resort to a hack.

Whenever you need to write raw XML keep a reference to the underlying writer and do the following:

```
// somewhere before:
Writer underlyingWriter = /* get the underlying writer from somewhere */;
XMLStreamWriter xmlStreamWriter = factory.createXmlStreamWriter(underlyingWriter);

xmlStreamWriter.flush();
underlyingWriter.write(rawXML);
underlyingWriter.flush();
// carry on using the XMLStreamWriter
```

You need to flush the xmlStreamWriter before using the underlying writer to ensure correct order of elements. Additionally you should flush the underlyingWriter for the exact same reason.